# changing img while clicking button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a jsp page that has buttons, and when i click the button a modal will open, and whatever happens inside that modal is linked with a js file (no more jsp). So here is my table inside modal (js file) :

```
html = '<table style="width:400px;height:250px;">'

    + '<tr><td title="grp"><img id="groupBtn" src="group.png"></td>'

            +'<td title="1st"><img id="1stBtn" src="1st.png""></td>'
```

as you can see, it's html code in js file and not normal code from jsp. (I don't know the exact term.)

Therefor I can't write the `<style></style>` tag for that table made in js file.

What I want to do: 
change the image while I'm clicking the button; not mouse enter, not image change, but `a:active`.

My problem:
it's in `img` tag and not `a` tag

so i tried

```
+ '<tr><td title="그룹"><a id="test1><img id="groupBtn" src="group.png"></a></td>'
```

this but the problem is i don't know where to put

```css
#test1:active{
    background-image : url('clicked.png');
}
```

while googling i found out this won't work because this is not how you change the src in img tag.

```
html = '<table style="width:400px;height:250px;">'

    + '<tr><td title="grp"><img id="groupBtn" src="group.png"></td>'

            +'<td title="1st"><img id="1stBtn" src="1st.png""></td>'
```

^ How should I reform this `<img id=>` to something that could work with `a:active` tag? Or, should i never even use a tag and just change the whole tag into something else? plus, if i want to give style to elements that were created in js file by html, where should i add the style tag?

---

To save your precious time helping me, i want to summarize a bit,
I want the image on my button to change only when my mouse is clicked (pressed more precisely) and then my mouse is no more pressed, i want my button image to return to original image. Thats why I said i want something that works like `a:active` tag cause it only changes your css when the mouse is pressed and changes back when mouse isnt pressed anymore !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

```
function imgToNew(){
  var image= document.getElementById('groupBtn');
  image.src = "newImage.png"; 
}

function imgToOrig(){
  var image= document.getElementById('groupBtn');
  image.src = "group.png";
}

<a id="test1" onmousedown="imgToNew()" onmouseup="imgToOrig()"><img id="groupBtn"  src="group.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change on click,you could add a onClick handler in a script tag instead of changing it via css.

```
<a id="test1" onclick="changeImgSrc()"><img id="groupBtn"  src="group.png"></a>
```

Somewhere in your js file,have this function.

```
  function changeImgSrc(){
      var groupImg = document.getElementById('groupBtn');
      groupImg.src = "clicked.png";   // path of the img
      return false // required to prevent default browser behaviour.
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but if i use this my image will change and won't comeback to first state. What i want is
button img -- (clicking) -- > clicked image -- (mouse not clicking anymore) --> button img

Answer (score 0):

Another option using css classes.

```css
.image{
  height:400px;
  width:600px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300') no-repeat;
}
.image:hover{
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/250/450?grayscale') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: Hello!! this is a brilliant code and i am so thankful you have replied me, but what i want is image changing only while my mouse is pressed ! I think i have made a confusion, ill edit my question

Comment: Look at the updated version, using :hover action on the image class you are able to change the background image. But the answer from anuragb26 is much more common and useful practice.

Comment: @HI You could do that by wrapping an `<a>` tag around the `div` and changing the second selector to `a:active .image`.

Comment: Oh thank you, but to change the selector setting i have to write style tag as xlsra's updated answer, but I dont know how to set style for js file cause <style></style> wont work :( all i know is to give style as <td style="like this"> but i dont think a:active is working on <td ~~~ > tag

Comment: Oh, looks like you don't even need `<a>`. You can just directly say `.image:active`.